Is there a human gene or allele that has dramatically changed in frequency of occurence in the past circa 500 years?
I'm a writer and engineer, not a biologist, so please forgive me on errors. I've done hours and hours of reading of biology texts and research papers trying to answer this question for myself before asking here.
Is there evidence for any allele that has dramatically changed in frequency of occurrence in the past 500 years (or in that time frame)?
I'm just trying to get an idea of whether a genome would provide any evidence of deriving from one century versus another, so to speak (i.e. I'm not really concerned with actual centuries, but rather changes over that time scale).

Update
See this very recent post on this topic from the excellent Sasha Gusev.
Original answer
I would suggest this recent review of the literature on techniques for detecting very recent selection in human populations and some of the results they've gotten.
Some of the least ambiguous results are as follows:

Markovian coalescent (ASMC) detects targets of recent positive selection by inferring pairwise coalescent times and looking for unusually high densities of coalescent events in the recent past (Fig 2C(v)) [16,17]. When applied to whole-genome sequences of approximately 3,200 individuals of European ancestry, SDS detected selection signals in the past 2,000 to 3,000 years in the major histocompatibility complex (MHC) region and at variants associated with lactose tolerance and pigmentation [15]. In comparison, application of ASMC to over 487,000 British individuals identified signals of selection in the past 1,500 years, including those detected by SDS, as well as several new candidate loci harboring genes related to immune response, tumor growth, and other phenotypes [17].
...
These new methods have confirmed strong selection on variants associated with lactase persistence, immune response, and pigmentation traits in Europeans in the past few thousand years and some signals in other populations (such as the EDAR gene in East Asians), although very few new signals have been detected. [my emphasis]

There are some more results in there. However, I would pay a lot of attention to the methodological issues and caveats that are given. It's very hard to detect this kind of thing, and the possibility of confounding is very high.
Furthermore, I am not sure that these constitute "dramatic" change in allele frequency of the kind that you seem to be interested in. For example, they have this to say about genes associated with resistance to pandemics like the Black Death (one of the most clear cut examples of selection on differential fitness).

These results suggest the selection effects of historical pandemics at individual genomic loci are relatively modest, necessitating expansive sample sizes for detection.

They are statistically detectable, implying that they are strong from a microevolutionary point of view, but it is not at all clear that they are significant from a historical point of view, or that they lead to meaningful group distinctions.
Looking at your interest in trying to "date" a genome like with carbon dating, that sounds difficult. A more answerable question might be, if you got very lucky and found an example of a distinct population group that died out, you might be able to put bounds on that person based on the existence of that group. But that's probably on the thousands of years scale (more) rather than hundreds.
In summary: recent evolution in humans is the exception and not the rule. Most of the important stuff happened prehistorically (like, out-of-Africa and before).

Thank you so much for taking the time to research and write a solid answer to my question.
I try hard to make my stories as scientifically accurate as possible.  It's a challenge sometime, as I have only basic college-level (physics, mostly) background in the sciences.
